# Not GCed FinalizerReferences with no referent?

Tags: java, android, c++, memory-management, hprof

I'm analyzing android app that uses c++ native code heavily (and even uses built-in V8 js engine) and has JNI glue classes. When trying to analyze memory usage with Android Studio i've found that there are lot's of retained FinalizerReferences with no referent.

1. i disabled instant run in Android Studio
2. i don't have any classes with finalize() method body
3. i clicked "Collect GC" before getting heap dump

[image]

Why i see so much FinalizerReferences? Why there are no referents? Shouldn't they be GCed?

Comment: It does seem strange. Did you force GC, wait for it to finish, then forced it again? To my understanding the first time you would trigger collection of the referents after running their finalize() methods, followed by removal of the corresponding instances of FinalizerReference from the list. The latter group would be available for collection only on the second round.